# Where to find the protobuf for aarch64?

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

As far as I can tell from the [protobuf release page](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v21.8), only the protobuf compiler (protoc) is released for aarch64, not the protobuf library itself.  And I read contradictory statements as to whether protobuf [is](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-on-arm64/) or [is not](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/28018) supported for that architecture.

So:

- Is protobuf for cpp supported on aarch64?
- If so, where can I find the binary?
- If not, why and how much trouble am I getting into building it from source from the repo?

Comment: Why not simply get the source, and cross-compile it for your target?

Comment: [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/libprotobuf32) has protobuf for arm64, so it is certainly possible to compile for it. The protobuf project itself does not seem to package precompiled libraries for **any** architecture, they expect you to build it yourself.